# Windows 10 programmatically reconnect USB FTDI

Tags: windows-10, usb, ftdi

We have an awful USB FTDI device (COM port) that usually requires us to disconnect and reconnect the USB cable to get the thing to work properly after a PC reboot. Sometimes it doesn't give us trouble, but more often than not it does. Unfortunately we are stuck with the device due to project momentum.

At this point, I'm willing to find a work-around just to save us that extra step every day.

Is there any way to programmatically disconnect and reconnect this USB FTDI cable? Be it a batch file, .NET application, Power-shell, etc? Something I could add as an auto-run startup program.

Comment: Maybe first try if disabling/re-enabling it in Device Manager helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Steps for Disabling/Enabling Hardware Devices Using Powershell`` (Run in **Administartor mode** !)

In this example, I will be disabling the Killer Networks E2400 Network Controller.
Step 1:  Confirm the device is present and enabled

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*ftdi*"  // HERE YOU HAVE TO USE A PART OF THE NAME AS SEEN IN DEVICE_MANAGER
```

A status of OK indicates the device is enabled.  The class, friendly name, and truncated InstanceId is also displayed.
Confirm the device is present and enabled using get-pnpdeviceConfirm the device is present and enabled using get-pnpdevice

Step 2:  Find the InstanceID of the device

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*ftdi*" | ft -wrap -autosize friendlyname, instanceid
```

This command returns the friendlyname and instanceid without truncating the values.
Use get-pnpdevice to find the instanceidUse get-pnpdevice to find the instanceid
Step 3: Disable the device using the InstanceID found in step 2

```
Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId "PCI\VEN_XXXX&DEV_XXXX&SUBSYS_E000XXXX&REV_10\4&325XXXX&0&00XX -confirm:$false
```

Copy the full InstanceId found in step 1 into the disable cmdlet.
use disable-pnp to disable the device using powershelluse disable-pnp to disable the device using powershell
Step 4:  Check your work using Get-PnpDevice

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*ftdi*"
```

A status of ‘Error’ indicates that the device is not enabled.  You can also check manually with the device manager.
get-pnpdevice shows the device is disabledget-pnpdevice shows the device is disabled

You can now re-enable the device by using enable-pnpdevice -instanceid as follows:

```
Enable-PnpDevice -InstanceId "PCI\VEN_XXXX&DEV_XXXX&SUBSYS_E000XXXX&REV_10\4&325XXXX&0&00XX" -confirm:$false
```

You can then confirm it is enabled by using get-pnpdevice one more time.  A status of ‘OK’ indicates that it is enabled.

```
Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*ftdi*"
```

If that works pack into a script and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks for the step by step details. I was able to find the correct device using Get-PnpDevice, but when I tried the Disable-PnpDevice command I received this message: "Disable-PnpDevice : Generic failure" "At line:1 char:1" "+Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId "FTDIBus\VID_0403+PID_6015+DN1V65V6A\0000" -confirm:$false" "+~~~~~~~~~~~" "   +CategoryInfo : NotSpecified:(Win32_PnpEntity...1V65V6A\000...):ROOT\cimV2\Win32_PnpEntity) [Disable-PnpDevice],CimException" "   +FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80041001,Disable-PnpDevice"

Comment: I guess its FTDIBUS\COMPORT&VID_0403&PID_6015&DN1V65V6A\0000 so the ampersand & and not the + AND the device is plugged in and enabled/ready

Comment: I'll try it. I just typed it exactly how it appeared during the "Get-PnpDevice -FriendlyName "*ftdi*" | ft -wrap -autosize friendlyname, instanceid" command

Comment: Okay, it turns out the original string was correct (with the plus signs). My problem was that I needed to run powershell in admin mode. Now it works!

Comment: Was my first thought but I did not dare to ask you if you were running in Admin mode - next timei'll do Thanks for the feedback I'll add tothe answer -Please mark as accepted